# How to solve original size problem of MLFlow Artifacts?

Tags: python, mlflow

I want to save my feature importance plot into mlflow project. But my figure size is looking like this; x axis names are cropped. How can i fix this problem?

Code;

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(forest_importances[-25:])
for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)
    
mlflow.log_figure(fig, "figure.png")
```

Normal;
[image]

In mlflow ;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to increase the figsize

```
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

Also another approach would to do horizontal plots, given the amount of x_axis that would be the most recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem. Just use

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

before `mlflow.log_fiture()`